# Числительное "шестисоттысячной" порядковое?

Tags: числительные

Почему в этом предложении числительное порядковое, неужели только из-за вопроса какой?

"Наполеон с шестисоттысячной армией вторгся на территорию России."

Здесь же говорится о численности армии, да и при склонении составного порядкового числительного изменяется только последнее слово.

Comment: @Дима 15, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то, порядковые числительные отвечают на вопрос "который?", а не "какой?". Но в приведенном Вами предложении уместен вопрос "с какой?" -с шестисоттысячной, т.е. многочисленной, поэтому это не числительное, а прилагательное. Подобное я встречал в одном из учебников: миллионный посетитель - который? (числительное), а миллионные тиражи книг - какие? (прилагательное)

Comment: Я своему учителю тоже сказал,что это прилагательное с количественным признаком,но она утверждает,что здесь порядковое числительное,т.к. отвечает на вопрос "какой"?.

Comment: Молодец, Дима, что отстаиваешь свою точку зрения!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте подставить вместо *шестисоттысячной* другое слово, явное порядковое числительное. С десятой армией? С сотой? С пятисотой? Ничего не получается. Значит, не числительное.

Comment: Но теоретически мы можем сказать о шестисоттысячном солдате армии, и тогда это порядковое числительное. Поэтому точнее сказать, что "шестисоттысячный" в разных предложениях может быть или порядковым числительным, или сложным прилагательным со значением количества.

Answer (score 0):

Тысяча, миллион, миллиард - особые слова. Они имеют числовое значение, как числительные, но при этом являются **грамматическими существительными**, то есть склоняются и участвуют в словообразовании как существительные.

Слов "тысячный, пятитысячный и т.д. могут быть как ПОРЯДКОВЫМИ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫМИ, ТАК И ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫМИ. Две разные функции соответствуют разным схемам образования:

1) пять тысяч - пятитысячный: который, порядковое числительное, сравнить: пять сотен - пятьсот - пятисотый;

2) пять тысяч - пятитысячный: какой, соответствует количеству предметов, лиц. Здесь тысяча используется  в качестве ЕДИНИЦЫ ИЗМЕРЕНИЯ, сравнить: пять метров - пятиметровый.

Убедиться в двойной роли слов "тысячный, пятитысячный" можно, обратившись к толковому словарю (например, на Грамота.ру), там указаны все их значения.

И по поводу составных порядковых числительных, в которых склоняется только последнее слово. Это верно для стоящих  в конце обычных числительных, например: две тысячи пятнадцатый год, но: двухтысячный год.

В то же время с помощью обычных числительных мы не можем определить численность отряда: пятитысячная армия, но отряд в триста человека. Функцию прилагательного обычные числительные выполнять не могут.

Comment: Кто же из нас прав?

Comment: Вы, разумеется, потому что шестисоттысячный - это сложное прилагательное (со значением "содержащий шестьсот тысяч человек), а не порядковое числительное. Для подтверждения своей точки зрения обратитесь к толковому словарю.

Comment:  Vera, спасибо. Это я для себя узнаю. А  учитель всё равно  не примет от ученика никаких возражений.

Comment: @Дима 15, а вы будьте убедительны. Объясните ей на приведенных здесь примерах. Главное - правильно объяснить!